# Embedding Firefox into a .NET control

Tags: c#, .net, firefox, webbrowser-control, instance

I am beginner in c# and .net programing and I want to know whether i can use Mozilla Firefox as instance browser of webBrowser control, as by default webBrowser control use Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 6):

The [Mozilla ActiveX Control](http://www.adamlock.com/mozilla/control.htm) uses the Gecko layout engine to deliver a fully programmable HTML and XML rendering control for ActiveX developers.

The API is similar to the Internet Explorer ActiveX control so it maintains a high degree of compatibility.

Gecko is the same engine that powers Mozilla, Mozilla Firefox

Comment: OK, and is there opera control available or not?

Comment: After download "Mozilla ActiveX Control" how do i use it in c#/.net as internet explorer i used webBrowser control like this: "webBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Text);" but how to use this Mozilla ActiveX Control.

Comment: Install the control / or compile it and ensure it is registered.  
In the "View" menu, click "Toolbox"  
Click the "Components" tab  
Right-click anywhere in the "Toolbox" and click "Customize Toolbox..."  
In the "COM Components" tab, check the "MozillaBrowser Class" and click "OK"  
The Mozilla Browser control should now appear as "Browser" in the "Toolbox" for insertion into any application. (Click and drag onto your form)  Mozilla control will implement the IWebBrowser and DWebBrowserEvents interfaces that Microsoft have already defined for Internet Explorer

Comment: One more thing i want to ask is when I'll create a sample web-browser program using "Mozilla ActiveX Control" will my program work in any PC or not(only in my PC)

Comment: help me, i got this error when i try "Mozilla ActiveX Control".
this is my code: `axMozillaBrowser1.Navigate("www.google.com");`

Error:-Unable to get the window handle for the 'AxMozillaBrowser' control. Windowless ActiveX controls are not supported.

in this code: `((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.axMozillaBrowser1)).EndInit();` in Form1.Design.cs

Comment: If you're using Vista and/or VS2008 [this link](http://objectmix.com/dotnet/308769-windowless-activex-controls-not-supported-error-vista-using-vs2008-pro-rtm.html) might help.

Comment: I see this project is no longer being actively developed and hasn't been updated in awhile. Does that mean that the engine is outdated? Will it handle newer technologies like HTML5 and CSS3?

Answer (score 2):

There's an old WinForms Gecko (Firefox) control somewhere, but the best non-IE .NET control you'll get is [Awesomium](http://awesomium.com/), which is based on Chrome.

Comment: After download "Awesomium" how do i use it in c#/.net
as internet explorer i used webBrowser control like this: "webBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.text);" but how to use this Awesomium.

Comment: [`webControl.Source`](http://docs.awesomium.net/html/P_Awesomium_Core_IWebView_Source) = `textBox.Text.ToUri();`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [Mozilla ActiveX control](http://www.adamlock.com/mozilla/control.htm#download) that you can use.

After you have installed it,
 in your Visual Studio go to

```
 Toolbox>right-click>choose items>COM Components>Mozilla Browser Class
```

Comment: help me, i got this error when i try "Mozilla ActiveX Control". this is my code: `axMozillaBrowser1.Navigate("www.google.com"); ` Error:-Unable to get the window handle for the 'AxMozillaBrowser' control. Windowless ActiveX controls are not supported. in this code: `((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.axMozillaBrowser1)).EndInit();‌`​ in Form1.Design.cs

Comment: i didn't have this problem, try with [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlanalysisservices/thread/e3ad503a-57fb-49b8-b6b9-01c9f4aa201e/)