# Run another application in windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, vbscript

Am creating a windows form ,call it test,ok this program should run firefox browser in it,how would i achieve this? have search the  entire net but no solution,thanks!

Comment: `Process.Start(firefox.exe)`

Comment: In terms of having the FireFox browser IN your form, there are many other posts on this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/790542/replacing-net-webbrowser-control-with-a-better-browser-like-chrome http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512284/alternative-to-webbrowser-control and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12083146/embedding-firefox-into-a-net-control

Answer (score 3):

No way to achieve firefox running as a part of your window. You can use [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx). Or you can utilize browser element which will be IE window.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can run an application INSIDE of a form but, you can start an application by doing this:

```
Process.Start("<insert file name and path>")
```